# How to catch error in loop Python correctly?

Tags: python

I read the file lines:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
   result = parse(line)
```

Inside `parse` method I have:

```
def parse(line):
    l = line.split(",")
    if not l[0]:
      raise Exception(1)
```

How to catch error for each line and if there is not exceptions to add result to dict?

```
result = parse(line)
// add to dict if line valid
```

And is it possible to pass `l` and message in `raise Exception(lm, "1")`?

Comment: do you know about try/except ?

Comment: Yes, but I can not get where to aply this in loop or outside, because I need to continues to read lines despite one line is incorrect

Comment: First is to imagine that there will be no exceptions. Please update your question with code that will `"add result to dict"`

Comment: Then inside the loop because if you catch exception outside you have already left the loop without processing the file lines after the error.

Comment: "add to dict" - its not clear how you would do that part. You have 1 thing, but dicts are key/value (2 things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this to trap the exception in the calling code:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    try:
        result = parse(line)
        mydict[index] = result
    except Exception:
        print(f"Line {index} is blank or has a leading comma: {line}")
```

You can (and should) use a more specific exception than `Exception` (for example `TypeError`) and you *can* create an exception with a message. But in your code as it stands, `parse()` doesn't know the line number so is not in a position to provide a helpful message. If your file is thousands of lines long it would be good to report *where* the error is. You could fix that by passing `index` as a parameter to `parse()` but I wanted to change your code as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `try/except` around the minimal code that needs to be verified, inside the loop

```
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    try:
        result = parse(line)
        # continue code that may raise exception
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed for:", line)
        print(errorCodes[e.args[0]])

    # or continue here
```

Use `e.args` to access the value passed when exception was raised

Comment: What if I pass custom number to `raise Exception(8)` how to check then in catch it?

Comment: Where 8 is `errorCodes = {8: 'Day',}`

Comment: @Alina use e.args, see my edit